# Is it possible to monitor/kill/nice linux runaway processes automatically?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm running Arch Linux and every so often a process (might be Firefox? Or Chromium? Or something else?) will eat my system. By that I mean that either CPU or RAM usage goes through the roof and my system appears to hang.

It's so bad that ssh appears to not respond. However the system is still doing *something* (the weird part about it is that it doesn't appear to really be using the CPU, as the fan doesn't start kicking on). I know for a fact that the system is still up and at least kind of operating, though, because I currently have a ssh tunnel through that system that is *kind of* still alive. And in the past eventually I've been able to ssh in and see the system usage through `htop`.

So what I would *like* to do is create maybe some cron script that runs ever 5 minutes, and if the system is basically locked up, identify the process and punch it in the face. I mean make it a little nicer, or kill it, or something so that I can actually use my system.

Is there anything like this that I could do?

Comment: Most likely you are out of RAM and swapping makes the situation worse. Can you reproduce the situation, if you have done `swapoff -a` ?

Comment: @EugenRieck the problem is entirely intermittent. It's been weeks or maybe even months since the last time it happened. I'm pretty sure that I remember at one point it was obvious that I was out of RAM and it was swapping a whole bunch, based on `htop`. Unfortunately it currently looks like things are super hung right now...